# Godot distorting pixels

Tags: 2d, godot, resolution, pixel, pixel-art

As the title says, Godot is stretching/distorting pixel art. It seems to be dependent on where on the screen the pixel is located.

I've already double-checked my project settings and searched several queries, to no avail. It looks okay in the preview and editor, but this happens when running. It doesn't matter whether it's debug or release, regular resolution or full screen, it still happens. Based on other people's posts, I think it's due to resolution issues, but I'm not sure.

If it's relevant, my screen has a resolution of 2560 × 1600.

[image: Example 1] [image: Example 2]

[image: Screenshot of Godot window settings]

Comment: I would do what this video recommends: [How to make a silky smooth camera for pixelart games in Godot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxVQsi9wnw8).

Comment: @Theraot Thank you! The video helped me figure it out. The camera zoom was set to 0.7 and changing it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue, which @Theraot helped me figure out, was that the camera was zoomed at a factor of 0.7, which caused issues since it didn't divide evenly. Changing to 0.5 fixed the problem.